# Thread1:EXC_BAD_instruction(code=exc_i386_invop,subcode=0*0) on tableView Project

Tags: ios, swift

Hey guys i just started Swift and i am having problems.I did give the label a tag and i implemented the UIViewController,UiTableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource. I did add in the storyboard the Delegate and the dataSource on the tableView but i keep getting this error

> Thread1:EXC_BAD_instruction(code=exc_i386_invop,subcode=0*0) on tableView Project 
>   on let lblName:UILabel = cell.viewWithTag(102) as! UILabel

```
      func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell")!

    //remplissage cell

    switch indexPath.section {
    case 0:
        let lblName:UILabel = cell.viewWithTag(102) as! UILabel
        lblName.text = "30/09/2200"

        let lblDate:UILabel = cell.viewWithTag(103) as! UILabel
        lblDate.text = "30/09/2200"

        //let imgProfile:UIImageView = cell.viewWithTag(103) as! UIImageView
      //  imgProfile.image = UIImage(named: "pexel")

    cell.textLabel?.text = "Firas"
    case 1:
        cell.textLabel?.text = "sqdqsd"
    default:
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Nothing"
    }



    return cell


}
```

Comment: did you set the tag in your storyboard?

Comment: Are you sure that your `cell` actually has a subview with that tag and it is UILabel? One of these statements is false for sure.

Comment: since you are using UITableViewCell then why dont you access the label like cell.detailTextLabel and cell.textLabel

Comment: yes i did add the tag on each label on the storyBoard.

Comment: the error appear on the lblName. I checked the tag and i checked that it s a label; so i am sure that it s correct

Comment: Try putting `print(cell.viewWithTag(102))` before the line that's causing trouble and let us know what it prints.

Comment: `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` can return `nil`. You have a lot of `!` in your code. Those are crashes waiting to happen.

Comment: Dealing with label tags is very old-fashioned. Design a custom cell with `IBOutlet`s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class FirasCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var date: UILabel!
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    // This will be an an option, as dequeue returns an optional
    // This also assumes that all your cells are FirasCells
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell") as?     FirasCell

    // Sure you aren't thinking of rows here? An array would be rows, an array of arrays would be sections with rows in them
    switch indexPath.section {
    case 0:
        cell?.name.text = "30/09/2200"
        cell?.date.text = "30/09/2200"

        cell?.textLabel?.text = "Firas"
    case 1:
        cell?.textLabel?.text = "Second Cell"
    default:
        cell?.textLabel?.text = "The rest of them"
    }

    // Quick and dirty check for this example as you are not allowed to return nil
    return cell ?? UITableViewCell()
}
```

It might be possible to figure out the tag solution, but it's not very reliable. A quick and easy solution is to create your own cell (see FirasCell above) and make sure your cell in your table in your storyboard is of that type. Then add your two labels as outlets.

Now your cell can be a `FirasCell` and you can directly set the text on them after dequeuing them. I've avoided using `!` in the example code as that outright crashes your app, so only use `!` if you are very very sure.

The trickiest part is probably setting up the outlets, but once you know how it's easy. There's a good amount of tutorials out there that do explain it better than me, but the short version is that you want to open the Connections inspector (the circle with an arrow to the right tab in the utility bar on the right) when you have the cell selected and then click drag from the circle next to your outlet to your UILabel.